# Constant contact API - get campaign Id from UI

Tags: php, wordpress, constantcontact

I am new to constant contact API for PHP. I created a campaign for email through UI.Now I want to use the API to send emails for which I need the "campaignID".

So My problem is how will I get the "campaignID" if I create the campaign through UI.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the campaign ID using the Campaigns Endpoint of our API:  http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/email-campaigns/email-campaigns-collection.html

This will also allow you to retrieve the name (so you know which campaign is which) and the status of each campaign.  To help reduce the number of results you can use the modified_since, status, and limit parameters in your query.

Hope this helps!  If not feel free to shoot me an email mstowe[at]constantcontact.com and I can help with the code :)